# Dismiss Dialog Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using this alert dialog:

```
public  void displayAlert() 
        { 
         new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setMessage(R.string.invitenotice)   
               .setTitle("Invite Notice")   
               .setCancelable(true)   
               .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,   
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){ 
                     finish();
                  }   
                  })   
               .show();  
        }
```

my problem is when I click ok I don't want to use finish(); I just want to dismiss the dialog. Any help is appreciated. Or maybe a more simple way of creating a simple dialog box when I press a button ? Thanks everyone. Also, a problem is I get 4-6 instances of the dialog box. So i need to press ok 4-6 times until it dissapears. Where I put the listener to my button is here :

```
   findViewById(R.id.mainHelp).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
            @Override 
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
                               displayAlert(); 
                   return false; 
}});
```

in the onCreate() method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove finish() default action is dismiss. so don't put anything in on click().

Answer (score 3):

Just set null as the listener, the dialog will dismiss itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `dialog.dismiss();` inside you're `onClick` method.

Comment: Yes but ''dialog'' is the parameter! (though it is true that a null listener is simpler and does the same)

Comment: Whoops, ignore my comment. Must be on a coffee low right now. :p

Comment: Null listener will also work, but only as long as you don't want to do anything else inside of onClick method

Answer (score 1):

Handle the scenario for Dialog box this way

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (which)
    {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
            break;
    }
}
```

On click of OK dialog box is dismissed automatically.

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Error!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Test!");
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.setButton(3,"Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {               
            finish();
            }
    });
```